# Facebook Graph API /{page-id}/feed does not return all posts of fb page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are trying to retrieve all posts of a certain facebook page via the Graph API.
The problem is that not all posts are returned. The posts are from different fb users who post on this public fan page.

We use '/{page-id}/feed' to fetch the posts. This also happens in the Graph API Explorer with all available permissions.

Any idea why this happens? 
Is it related to the users privacy settings or is fb filtering these posts for some reason?
Could it be region, spam filtering?

We really would like to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was the users settings.

Settings->Apps->Apps others use

When "My photos" is not checked in the users settings, the API will not return those posts even if posted on a public page.